# "Could not access KVM kernel module" on Ubuntu Virtual Machine

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu

I am trying to run a program that uses QEMU on an Ubuntu VM in VirtualBox hosted on a Windows 10 computer with an AMD CPU. When I try to run the program it gives me this error:

```
Could not access KVM kernel module: No such file or directory
qemu-system-x86_64: failed to initialize kvm: No such file or directory
```

I've tried a lot of solutions posted online. [This](https://github.com/foxlet/macOS-Simple-KVM/issues/252) one appeared the most promising. However, when I run

```
sudo modprobe kvm_amd
```

it gives me this error:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'kvm_amd': Operation not supported
```

Tried to fix that with no luck. I ran virt-host-validate and got:

```
QEMU: Checking for hardware virtualization                                 : FAIL (Only emulated CPUs are available, performance will be significantly limited)

  QEMU: Checking if device /dev/vhost-net exists                             : PASS

  QEMU: Checking if device /dev/net/tun exists                               : PASS

  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'cpu' controller support                         : PASS

  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'cpuacct' controller support                     : PASS

  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'cpuset' controller support                      : PASS

  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'memory' controller support                      : PASS

  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'devices' controller support                     : WARN (Enable 'devices' in kernel Kconfig file or mount/enable cgroup controller in your system)

  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'blkio' controller support                       : PASS

  QEMU: Checking for device assignment IOMMU support                         : WARN (Unknown if this platform has IOMMU support)

  QEMU: Checking for secure guest support                                    : WARN (Unknown if this platform has Secure Guest support)
```

Other solutions have suggested messing around with VirtualBox settings, this is what I got from trying those:
[image]
[image]

This hasn't helped fix it. Other solutions mention going to the BIOS to fix it, but since this is a VM there doesn't seem to be a way to do that in VirtualBox.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, trying to use `podman` (start virtual machine), in Ubuntu.

Comment: Unfortunately never found a solution to this problem. My solution was to just dual boot Ubuntu on an old laptop. I've left it up in case someone ever figures it out.

Answer (score 0):

it may be too late, but i meet the same problem just now.
this is my solution:

1.dmesg | grep kvm ，look if have kvm: disabled by bios，then reboot and go to bios setting.

2.if cpu is amd, look for svm mode, enable.

3.lsmod | grep kvm, if there is

```
   kvm_amd                29264  0
   kvm                    244765  1 kvm_amd
```

then means kvm load successfully.

4.start your virtual machine.